# OpenGL glRasterPos doesn't properly accept my Values

Tags: c++, opengl, glu

I've been trying to add some basic HUD-like Text to my OpenGL/C++ project.

Therefore i decided

```
glutBitmapCharacter( type, character)
```

to be my weapon of choice.

I realized that, for the easiest use, i should append a 2D Matrix to my previous Rendering area.

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, 10, 0, 10);
```

This should give me a sweet 10*10 2D cube to play around in.

Now a problem arised when glutBitmapCharacter remembers his last character position to append the next one. Pretty smart while it's writing a string, it obviously remembers this position and makes my Text fly all the way across screen once :) Naughty.

```
glRasterPos2f(x,y);
```

should be - as i heard - the normal thing to reset this thingy - (altough i don't perfectly understand why a gl function controls a glu Function, but thats just a sidenote).

Now the weird thing that happens, is once i run the code:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, 10, 0, 10);

string message ="mmh... Pie...";
float poss[3];

glRasterPos3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, poss);
std::cout<< "X" <<(GLfloat) poss[0] << " Y"<<poss[1] << " Z"<<poss[2] <<  std::endl;

   for( size_t i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i ) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, message[i]);
    }
glPopMatrix();
```

My Text doesnt get shown. In fact the resulting X, Y and Z
(not even sure Z is necessary.. should be 0 anyway) are all inf (infinite).
If i don't set my own glRasterPos, things just work out fine, apart from leaving the screen. My returning positions are an upcounting X and 0 , 0 - as expected.

So whats the deal on this, what exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check if `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION` is accepted in this call? (by `glGetError`) It's removed in 4.3. `RasterPos` controls `glu` function because this glu function uses GL functionality, so they share some state.

Comment: Oh, and, also, dusting off the 1.5 spec I found that default raster position is `(0, 0, 0, 1)` (its type is R^4). Try passing `float[4]` to `Get`.

Comment: It's actually exactly other way round: GLU and GLUT functions control OpenGL state. And the glutBitmapString functions don't reset OpenGL state, so everything those helper functions do, is based on OpenGL state. If you change that state, you change the way the helper functions behave.

Comment: thanks for the replys, but neither did glGetError return anything(GL_NO_ERROR), nor did  the changing to 4f change something, i still get inf returned : /

Comment: Uhwh... Okay, one more idea. Download gDebugger (free, from gremedy website) and run it on your code. It will automatically check for all errors (profit!) and will allow you to look into internals (you can see `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION` value) directly.

Answer (score 0):

you produced a grand Segmentation Error: glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, poss) returns 4 values, so you must use:

```
float poss[4];
```

Apart from this, your code runs fine on my machine and returns:

```
X0 Y0 Z0.5
```

So the fault seems not to be in the code you posted here. You should try&copy it to a basic "HelloWorld"-GL program and see if it works there. Be careful that some OpenGL commands only work after a valid drawing surface is initialized - I guess you did that?

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

I tried adding my Code to a GL-'hello-world' program, however it showed the same issue (had to add glutInit() aswell in that case).

I certainly get a feeling that my libraries are somewhat broken :) Still trying to figure out whats the deal there, aparently gDebugger doesn't run on my local configuration aswell, if i manage to get any usefull results out of it, i'll post them here asap :)